# How to call Wrapper (parent) method in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to solve this problem. I want to call `Wrapper.onClickHandler` method from `li` element because I would like to handle click action through `Wrapper` component. Is this possible?

```
class CallA extends Component {
  
  onClickHandler() {
    console.log('Call A Clicked');
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="call_a">
        {this.props.children}
      </ul>
    );
  }
  
}

class CallB extends Component {
  
  onClickHandler() {
    console.log('Call B Clicked');
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="call_b">
        {this.props.children}
      </ul>
    );
  }
  
}

class List extends Component {
  
  render() {
    
    const listType = props.listType;
    
    const WrapperComponents = {
      a: CallA,
      b: CallB
    }
  
    const Wrapper = WrapperComponents[listType];
    const Options = []
    
    for( const key in {a:1,b:2} ){
      Options.push(
        <li key={key} onClick={Wrapper.onClickHandler}>{key}</li>
      )
    }
    
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        {Options}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

calling different component conditionally.

```
const ComponentA = () => {
  const doSomething = () => {
       console.log('Dosomething in componentA')
  }

  return <li onClick={doSomething()} />
}

const ComponentB = () => {
  const doSomething = () => {
       console.log('Dosomething in componentB')
  }

  return <li onClick={doSomething()} />

}

class Wrapper extends Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <List />
      </ul>
    );
  }
  
}

class List extends Component {
  
  
  render() {

    return (
      <>
        {  Object.keys({a:1, b:2}).map(key => {
            return key === 'a' ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />
         }
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't call `Wrapper` first. `List` will be called first and `Wrapper` is dynamic component depending on the `List.props`.

Comment: then why your click function is in Wrapper? Maybe you briefly describe what you are trying to do so can give u better solution. If the way you handle your props onClick event, and the relationship between your parent/child component appears weird, then you need to rethink how your component should work.

Comment: I have edited my question. Let me know if that helps you to understand my problem better.

Comment: I assume you want to call different components conditionally. I've modified the code to show how we normally do it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is commonly known as passing a rendering function as a child component (FaCC), as opposed to passing components the usual way. Although it could be considered an anti-pattern, it is very powerful if used wisely.

This is how it works: you define a rendering function (`renderOptions` in your case) in one component and you pass the functions' reference as `props.children` to another component (`CallA` in your example). Thus, you will be able to call this function with any arguments you like by doing `{this.props.children(arg)}`. Your implementation should look like this:

```js
class CallA extends Component {
  onClickHandler() {
    console.log('Call A Clicked');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="call_a">
        {this.props.children(this.onClickHandler)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

/* ... */

class List extends Component {
  render() {
    const listType = this.props.listType;
    const WrapperComponents = {
      a: CallA,
      b: CallB
    }
    const Wrapper = WrapperComponents[listType];

    function renderOptions(onClickHandler) {
      const Options = [] 
      for( const key in {a:1,b:2} ){
        Options.push(
          <li key={key} onClick={onClickHandler}>{key}</li>
        );
      } 
      return Options;
    }
    
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        {renderOptions}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```